# List Out of Bounds of 1

Tags: webservices, soap

I am checking for products duplicated in my webservice but it is showing a "List Out of Bounds of 1" error in the below code.

```
     **for(integer j=0.prodsj++)** // Error Occur Point
      {

      {
        p = new  Product2(isActive=true);
      }
         p.Name =pName;         
            p.productCode = pCode;
            pList.add(p); 
      }


         Database.upsert(pList);   

        for(integer j=0;j<req.accounts[i].qline.size();j++)

       {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being able to see the whole code, my advice would be to start by replacing the "CHECK THE LOOP ONCE" code with the following where I have replaced the re-use of the i variable to see if that resolves the bounds error at least.

```
for( integer x = 0;x< req.accounts.size(); x++) 
{ //  CHECK THE lOOP ONCE                      

    for(integer j=0;j<req.accounts[x].prods.size();j++)
    {
        pCodeSet.add(req.accounts[x].prods[j].pCode);
    }
}
```

When this piece of code is finished the i variable will be in the state it was before entering the code because we haven't modified it with the for loop.

Assuming there is nothing else putting the i variable outside the bounds of the list, future use of the i variable in the code should not cause the bounds error.

ie

```
…
if(existpccMap.containsKey(req.accounts[i].prods[j].pCode))  // now safe
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: shall i share my whole code.

Comment: @Sathya - Does the change I suggested remove the 'List Out of Bounds of 1' Error?

Comment: I chage my code like this it is work for multiple records insert.

Comment: now i am not getting any error but i have a doubt my code works for multiple products insert or not..?

Comment: One issue you may have with multiple new products is if you add two with the same product code that don't exist already so are not in the existpccMap map. Where you create a new Product2 you should add it to the existpccMap map so if another new product comes along it can use the one you just created. It sounds like you've solved the question you asked and I think we're going a bit beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: my doubt is i want to change my code existpccMap.containsKey(req.accounts[k].prods[j].pCode) in place of K i want place k or i .that is my doubt.

Answer (score 3):

```
for( i = 0;i< req.accounts.size(); i++){ //  CHECK THE lOOP ONCE

     for(integer j=0;j<req.accounts[i].prods.size();j++)
     {
        pCodeSet.add(req.accounts[i].prods[j].pCode);
     }
}
```

Above `for` loop is updating the variable `i` of your main `for` loop and after this for loop `i` will have the value of `req.accounts.size()`. Then in the next `for` loop since you are using the same `i` it's throwing the exception. Reset it or manage it according to your business.

```
**for(integer j=0;j<req.accounts[i].prods.size();j++)** // Error point
      {
      if(existpccMap.containsKey(req.accounts[i].prods[j].pCode))
...
```

Comment: i am inside the main for loop  or shall i share my whole code.may i know where i want to change my code.

Comment: Yes it'd be better. Edit the question and add it(point where the exception occurs as you currently doing). According to the posted code you are outside of the top `for` loop.

Comment: i update my code can you check it once. And I add the point where i am getting an error.

Comment: i posted my updated code can you check it once.

Comment: Still the same issue there. One before `for` loop(not the loop having the query) is updating the variable `i` and so all the below codes refer that updated value, which tend to throw an out of bound exception.

Comment: can i change this for( i = 0;i< req.accounts.size(); i++){  loop variable i to k.

Comment: @hihfive can you give me update code for duplicates checking of products.

Comment: then how can i change the for loops for duplicate checking of the products.

Comment: I think it's another question to post. Also need to go through the business carefully. Sorry, at the moment have time only for investigate the raised issue